# Calculate Totals Of FormArray Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I wanted to multiply the num1 to num2 and put it to the subtotal. and if I push another row it will also multiply the num1 to num2

Lastly I want to add all the subtotal and put it in total how to achieve that?

here is my stackblitz that i created

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-scrwra

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-j3qmzy?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Please post all of the necessary info *on this site*, and not rely on a third party like stackblitz to hold the details required to answer the question. If something happened to that link in the future, this question would be mostly useless for anyone else that might find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing is add `change` event on input element then pass index as argument

```
  <td>
      <input
        type="number"
        (change)="onChange(i)"
        formControlName="num1"
        style="width:70px;2px"
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="number"
        (change)="onChange(i)"
        formControlName="num2"
        style="width:70px;2px"
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="number"
        (change)="onChange(i)"
        formControlName="subtotal"
        style="width:70px;2px"
      />
    </td>
```

Then finally based on index you can access `num1` and `num2` control and calculate total

```
 onChange(index:number){
    const total = (this.Info.at(index).get('num1').value || 0) +
    (this.Info.at(index).get('num2').value || 0);
    this.Info.at(index).get('subtotal').setValue(total);
  }
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-3ic2wu?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I like this solution, but since everything is mapped to a form, should not we rely on the methods valueChanges of the arrayForm instead of the (change) event of the input itself ?

Comment: @JoSeTe4ever If we listen valueChanges on formGroup when ever value changes in single form control we need to re evaluate all form array values

Comment: @Alluring you can use reduce array method to calculate total value. update my stackblitz please check

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using angular form value changes like this:

```html
this.Info.valueChanges.subscribe((datas: Array<any>) => {
      var total = 0;
      datas.forEach((data, index) => {
        const sub = data.num1 * data.num2;
        total = total + sub;
        this.Info.controls[index]
          .get('subtotal')
          .patchValue(sub, { emitEvent: false });
      });
      this.fg.get('total').patchValue(total);
    });
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-qw3kpz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html